# Net Configuration Assistant doesn't open, created Listener in Net Manager but it isn't recognized when creating database Win 7

Tags: oracle, configuration, listener

I have installed Oracle 11g on my Windows 7 64-bit system. The Net Configuration Assistant does not open for me to create a listener. I was able to add a listener through the Net Manger and it says it is configured correctly. But when I create a database it doesn't recognize the listener so I have to uncheck "Configure Enterprise Manager" in order to complete the creation of my database.

Is there another way to access the Net Configuration Assistant other than through the start menu so that the listener will be recognized by the database?

Comment: Have you ran the NetCA as Administrator? Open command prompt as Administrator and type netca(You have to set path to Oracle Home) then create listener. Also provide the Oracle database version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Netca "as Administrator".

The way Net Configuration Assistant and Net Manager create listener is the same - they both create configuration file - listener.ora. The difference is - Netca starts the service, but Net Manager is not.

Also, you can check if your listener is running by looking into Control Panel - Administration - Services - something like "OracleOraDB11gHome1TNSListener".

Answer (score 0):

It is a well known, but poorly documented, issue in that if you try to configure dbcontrol (enterprise manager) as part of the database creation, the database won't be registered with the listener in time for the dbcontrol creation, which requires a listener connection.  My standard procedure is to simply not select to create/configure dbcontrol as part of database creation.  After the database creation is complete and you confirm it is registered with the listener, come back with dbca and configure enterprise manager.